# How to make my Joomla admin login page working

Tags: joomla, authentication, configuration, phpmyadmin, backend

Somehow, my Joomla admin login page is stopped working, so the page loads but when I enter the username and password, it only refreshes and nothing happens. I cannot access the backend.
I use Joomla 1.5.

Any solution?

Comment: Is there any event on your part that may have caused this? Otherwise you could have been hacked

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was an issue with the PHP.ini file. I had to open the C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.ini file and save it with the encoding option UTF-8. 
I had increased the post_max_filesize to 30MB (I entered 30MB), I also changed this to 30M.

Back up and logging in.

WOOHOO - I hope this helps others as well. Simple little things are the hardest to find.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION FOR ME:

(Before doing anything with your database, ALWAYS BACKUP).

I have Joomla 2.5

1. I went to PhpMyAdmin
2. I clicked "jos_Extensions"
3. I went to the line which says "plg_user_joomla" and I set (1) for both "Enable" and "Access" columns.

then BOOM! It worked for me.

I hope that helps someone because I was struggling with this problem for days.

Comment: this Ali.. I had also the same problem and follow you and got succeed 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

can you please try the fallowing,

This problem is the one of the most discussed(sadly no suitable solution for it) topics in Joomla forum. Many users have posted different answers for this problem, worked out for some but not for all... We, at eManipur! also encounter this problem once and we had a hard time finding a good solution for it. Now we are sharing our solution with you guys(you know Sharing is fun,lol)....

We will list all the solutions( posted on Joomla forum, that worked for others) too.

1.Log into phpMyAdmin and navigate to the jos_plugins table.Look for the "User - Joomla!" and Joomla - Authentication.Ensure that both of them are published(set it to 1).

2.In the php.ini, set `session.use_cookies = 1`. If you are not allowed to edit your `php.ini` file then simply create a file called php.ini and stored it on your root folder.

3.Upload all your files properly(if you have uploaded manually via FTP software), particularly the plugins folder.

4.in the configuration.php remove any whitespace or linebreak  before "`?>`" or after `<?php`.Save it and upload the file.

5.Make sure all your folders have correct directory permissions( 755 is the advisable permission level for folders).

6.If you use SSL, then go into your site either through your web hosting control panel or FTP access, find your configuration.php file which should be found in the main root of the site. Edit the file, you should find; "`var $force_ssl = '1';`" switch this to 0 to disable it. Upload the file back to the site and check the administration page if it logs through `http://`

7.Clean all session (in table jos_session through phpMyAdmin)this

8.What we did :: We concluded that the presence of Byte Order Mark(BOM) in the configuration.php file make this admin login to loop. FYI, BOM is invisible in some editors like Notepad,Vim etc.. We used Notepad++ to save the file as `UTF8`(without BOM) encoding format., this will remove the BOM. After this, we could login into our admin panel without any indefinite for-loop (lol)

thank you.

Comment: You should recommend the user makes a backup of their sites before making such changes. It's an obvious thing to do, however some may not take it into consideration or other may forget.

Answer (score 0):

In phpMyAdmin check if the plugin *User - Joomla!* is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

it is may be due to wrong session lifetime setting in your global configuration.

Go to your joomla directory and open the file configuration.php.

In the session_lifetime change it to 15.

Answer (score 0):

in my case
Go to Phpmyadmin
 select database 
click on jos_plugin 
select user-joomla 
on publised field if it is 0 then change it to 1
click on go 
and noew login

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me after trying all possible solutions on web..

I was using Joomla 3.2.2 I tried to downgrade the version to Joomla 3.2.1 but it didn't work.. then I tried the version 3.2.0 and that worked for me..

Maybe you would tell you can't downgrade Joomla version YES but NO you can do it manually..

Just upload Joomla source package (3.2.0) extract the zip file on your current version..
that would overwrite the existing files.. But don't forget to take a back up of your "configuration.php"

After extracting the install package, don't forget to delete the "installation" folder..

Then overwrite the backed up "configuration.php" file with the existing file...

hope it would work for you as it did for me!